# EF6 - Return calculated grouped results within a single query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a usage table which stores daily usage for customers of various products. I want to now return a result which groups results by customerID for total / combined usage of various products.

See below a perfectly illustrated example of the current data structure :)

- id | customerID | prod1 | prod2
- 1 . 123 . 0 . 1
- 2 . 125 . 5 . 5
- 3 . 125 . 1 . 1

I am looking to return a result set as such (again, admire my illustrating ability):

- customerID | prod1 | prod2
- 123 . 0 . 1
- 125 . 6 . 6

Will this kind of calculation be possible using EF? I am trying to avoid a multitude of loops to achieve the same thing so this would greatly help a brother out.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `GroupBy` and `Sum`:

```
var result = context.Customers
    // .Where(filter) // filter if needed
    .GroupBy(m => m.CustomerID)
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        CustomerID = g.Key, // We grouped according to CustomerID, so key = CustomerID
        SumProd1 = g.Sum(m => m.Prod1), // Sum Prod1 of grouped data
        SumProd2 = g.Sum(m => m.Prod2) // Sum Prod2 of grouped data
    })
    .ToList();
```

**Note:** `ToList()` is for retrieving data, it is not needed if you plan to work on query.

Comment: virtual high5 coming your way!